# Curl not returning data

Tags: php, curl

Hi there i am using following code to get url data but getting nothing

```
$url = "http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B002P44QH2";
$ch = curl_init();echo $url;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
curl_close($ch);
return $page;
```

When i do print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)) it returns the following output:

```
    Array
(
    [url] => http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B002P44QH2
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0
    [namelookup_time] => 0.10347
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
)
```

When i do this in terminal it gives me following error

```
curl -I http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B002P44QH2
```

Error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 178.236.5.39: Network is unreachable
```

Please Help

Comment: do a var_dump() or print_r ton $page

Comment: This code works fine. Is this a real question?

Comment: yes mate it is real queston and i think it might have connection error, because when i try to ping any ip address it returns connect: Network is unreachable

Comment: The error message you're getting is pretty obvious. You don't have a connection to the internet. There is a finite number of possible explanations for this... I'd start with firewall, anti-virus, etc. first.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a shared hosting server, if yes then some shared hosting server wont allow curl requests - check this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/9953646/308251

Comment: it works fine on live server but doesn't work locally. and we have our own server not shared